# Powershell command that only works properly for a few files

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a bunch of files named `001.jpg`, `002.jpg` and so on. I'd like to rename them `Gym Heroes - 001 (US).jpg`, etc. I wrote this Powershell command:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName { "Gym Heroes - " + $_.name.Insert(3," (US)") }
```

This works as expected when there are 35 or fewer pictures, but starting from 36 pictures, all the pictures are weirdly renamed (`Gym Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - Gym (US) Heroes - 016 (US).jpg`) and I get the following error message for each file (not the exact error message since I translated it to English):

```
Rename-Item : Part of the access path is impossible to find.
At character Line:1 : 7
+ dir | Rename-Item -NewName { "Gym Heroes - " + $_.name.Insert(3," (US ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\Downloads... - 062 (US).jpg:String) [Rename-Item], DirectoryNotFoundE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommande
```

I don't understand at all why this is happening... I could rename my pictures 35 by 35 but I'd like to understand why my command doesn't work properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your dir/gci command in parentheses to force it to evaulate first. Otherwise you can get some items that appear to be processed multiple times.

So...

```
(dir) | Rename-Item -NewName { "Gym Heroes - " + $_.name.Insert(3," (US)") }
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this use of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest properly looping through your files and renaming one by one.

```
dir | % {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName { "Gym Heroes - " + $_.name.Insert(3," (US)") }
}
```

I'm not sure about how piping `Rename-Item` from the `dir` command works exactly.

Anyway, tested this with 2,000 files.